# How do I make operator properties show up as a dropdown in keymaps?

Tags: python

I've just learned about property definitions in operators. I can't find an answer on how to set them up in a way that their possible options appear as a dropdown in the Keymap panel. Like this one:

[image: example of proper dropdown]

I've managed to get something to appear there by inserting something into `default = ''` but that's about it.

```
uitype: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name = 'uitype',
        default = 'Something',
        #preset_options = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
        )
```

How do I program that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I just figured it out. I needed to use `bpy.props.EnumProperty`

```
uitype: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = 'uitype',
        items = (
            ('Something1', "Something 1", ""), 
            ('Something2', "Something 2", ""), 
            ('Something3', "Something 3", ""))
        )
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#enum-search-popup